# list<pair<,>> :: iterator vs vector<list<pair<,>>>: is there a simple way to search an element in these 2? find() isn't helpful

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, mapping

I have to search a `{key, value}` pair in a `vector<list<pair<int, int>>>`. There are 2 ways I tried doing this:

1. Using an iterator

   ```
   list<pair<int, int>> :: iterator search(int key)
    {
        int h = hash_func(key);
        auto itr = v[h].begin();
        while(itr!=v[h].end())
        {
            if(itr->first==key)
                return itr;
            itr++;
        }
        return itr;
    }
   ```

   This approach works just fine!
2. However, I tried another approach - using find() function

   ```
   list<pair<int, int>> :: iterator search(int key)
    {
        int h = hash_func(key);
        return find(v[h].begin(), v[h].end(), key);
    }
   ```

   I'm getting the following error:

> error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::pair<int, int>'
> and 'const int')
> { return *__it == _M_value; }

I'm still new to STL and have not been able to figure out where I'm going wrong!

I'm aware that the find function is supposed to return an iterator pointing to a `{key, value}` pair. The fact that I'm using a list of pair, will I still be needing  to update some iterator as I was doing in the 1st approach?

Comment: That question is about `std::set`, not `std::list`, but the answer is the same - you need a lambda to search by specific element of the pair. C++20 ranges could be used to avoid lambda.